# Light normalization of Orthophotos to increase comparability

Tags: comparison, rgb, orthophoto, normalize

I would like to work with the RGB-values of different orthophotos. Now I noticed that the light conditions are not the same in the different orthophotos. I was wondering if there is a sound way to make these images a bit more comparable. I found quite some studies about 'multitemporal normalization' for exactly the same region. My images are not images of the exact same region though, but they are close by each other.

If I adapt the min-max values I might falsify too much because different objects in the photos reflect differently of course.

Does anyone have a sound solution for adapting these images (at least a bit). Or do you have recommendations what I could search for (because I run out of search terms)?

Comment: "Histogram matching" could give some useful results.

Comment: To make them more comparable you can at least remove the scattering and absorption effects from the atmosphere [link](https://gisgeography.com/atmospheric-correction/). The buzz term is **Atmospheric Correction** (Top and bottom of atmosphere correction). Where do your images come from (Sentinel2?) ?

Comment: Thanks for the tips for better searching terms. The images are normal airplane orthophotos with 4 bands.